# How do I express the following limit as a definite integral?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

I have difficulty understanding the limit since it doesn't include the summation notation and I don't quite understand how should I express it as an integral. Also, if I just evaluate the limit, it seems that it just gives zero, so I'm not sure if there's something that I'm not getting.

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left[\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2}{n}+3\right) \sqrt{5+\frac{2}{n}}+\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(\frac{4}{n}+3\right) \sqrt{5+\frac{4}{n}}+\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)\left(\frac{6}{n}+3\right) \sqrt{5+\frac{6}{n}}+\cdots\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)(5 \sqrt{7})\right]$$

Comment: Hello! You need to include the problem. Ah, I see that there is a link in that tiny "1" at the end. Please add a label to make it more noticeable.

Comment: Also, the pattern is not at all clear from the expression.  In the third term, should that $\frac{n}{n}$ be $\frac{2}{n}$? and what is up with the last term?

Comment: Since $7=5+\frac{2n}{n}$, I assume this is a problem of the form $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nu_{nk}$. It's just a matter of defining $u_{nk}$, as @RobertTheTutor suggested.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention that there is a typo in the question. Indeed it should be 2/n everywhere and not n/n or 1/n.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your  limit is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n {\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\left(\frac{2i}{n} + 3\right) \sqrt{5 + \frac{2i}{n} }}$$
the integral is going to be $$\int_0^1{2\left(2 x + 3\right) \sqrt{5 + 2 x} \, dx}$$
[In general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_sums), the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{n}f\left( \frac{i}{n}\right)$$
is equal to the integral $$\int_0^1{f(x)\, dx}$$